# Installing PHP 7.3 Zip Extension

Tags: php, centos, php-extension, php-ziparchive

I have downloaded zip extension for PHP 7.3 on CentOS by typing the following command

```
yum install php73-php-pecl-zip
```

and added `extension=zip.so` to php.ini file, also restarted httpd service.

Still cannot see zip extension in `phpinfo()` and in my code I still get `Class 'ZipArchive' not found in...` error.

What should I do?

Comment: Could you try to create the object as `$var = new \ZipArchive`

Comment: didn't work :/ @Anders

Comment: Try running this command on your Centos machine :) `sudo service php-fpm restart`

Comment: still getting the same error :( @Anders

Comment: Hmmm... Could you check if the zip.so is placed in your PHP installations default folder? You can find that location in your php.ini (extension_dir)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I copied zip.so to default extension directory

No.

If you use base package (php-*) you need **php-pecl-zip**.

**php73-php-pecl-zip** is a SCL package designed for parallel installation.

See the repository [FAQ](https://blog.remirepo.net/pages/English-FAQ#scl)

For a proper configuration, and to avoid such issues, follow the [Wizard](https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/) instructions.

Comment: Yeah I tried php-pecl-zip too. But yum detected conflict with my php version (it was for php 7.2) so removed the package instantly. Because of that I tried php73-php-pecl-zip package. I was not aware of that wizard, will use it from now on. so thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I ran following command to find out where the package installed

```
rpm -ql php73-php-pecl-zip
```

as a result of that I could see the directory where the so file installed.

```
/opt/remi/php73/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/zip.so
```

I copied zip.so to default extension directory

```
cp /opt/remi/php73/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/zip.so /usr/lib64/php/modules/zip.so
```

And finally restarted httpd server.

Thanks to @Anders who gave me that idea